# What are these lines of colour on my Epson Perfection V370 scans?

Tags: scanning, computer-hardware

I have started to notice vertical stripes of colour on all of my (document table) scans. What might the cause be, and is there a fix? My scanner is an Epson Perfection V370 Photo, purchased ~3 years ago. It has not been used very often.

First image demonstrates a plain white scan which shows clear bands of colour. Second image is an edited version where I've increased the contrast to illustrate the issue.

[image]
[image]

Comment: For comparison, what does a "good" plain white scan look like after boosting the contrast? No lines or fainter lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem: Hardware issue

I have tried:

1. different scanning software
2. different USB cable (to rule out communication errors)
3. cleaning the document table with a dry cloth
4. cleaning the document table with a moist cloth
5. cleaning the white calibration strip (internal)
6. cleaning underside of glass (internal)
7. cleaning the sensor

Unfortunately, none of the above worked.

Epson have reviewed the case and have informed me it is a hardware issue, so there is no fix without paying for an engineer to look at it (as it happens, the fee for this is higher than the cost of the original unit).

Posting these notes here in case they're helpful for others.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a calibration issue. Since the pixels on the sensor do not all have the same sensitivity, the scanner should auto-calibrate every time it is powered on. I'm not entirely sure how it does this and the documentation doesn't give any indication. It may scan a test strip internal to the scanner or it may scan the white document mat.

However, your document table (glass) appears to be dirty and this may be the cause of your problem. Another possibility is dirt on the sensor or on the calibration strip (if this is internal to the scanner). Before you try anything else, I would recommend that you do the following:

1. Power off the scanner.
2. Clean the document table and mat in accordance with the
   manufacturer's instructions. Make sure that they are spotlessly
   clean but take care not to scratch them.
3. Insert the document mat and power on the scanner with the lid closed
   and no document inserted.
4. Perform some test scans to see if the problem is resolved.

Always switch the scanner off when you have finished using it.

Comment: thank you for the thorough answer. Will try some of your suggestions and report back.

Comment: ok, I tried:

1. cleaning the document table with a dry cloth
1. cleaning the doucment table with a moist cloth

Comment: A few minutes ago, I was about to take my scanner back for the second time but cleaning the glass certainly solves the problem. I am scanning thousands of slides in strips and have the film holder taped in place so I don't have to make adjustments to its position. Lifting it up showed the dust build-up had happened. So thank you Mick! I can get on with the job. PS: I also found it quicker to scan the strip as one image and then use Photoshop to chop it up into individual frames which I do while the next strip is scanning.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with my EPSON V370. It was first noticed when a colored line appeared on scanned slides. Cleaning the glass screen of dust particles solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have an Canon 9000f mkII and the solution was to clean one if the 3 internal mirrors that has the scan module carriage, mirrors that are wide as a A4 and 1cm high, and take the image from the glass surface to the lens and optical sensor st the end.
Please , be careful, use only special tisue with crear care, only breath to humidify something ... And  blow airvto tske any particle that the tisue could lay.
Clean the plate big glass from the scanner  below  also justo in case it's dirty.
Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem on my Epson Perfection V370. I tried to clean the glass again and again and it did not help at all. I solved the problem only after opening the scanner and cleaning the glass from the inside.